# Как отправить смс от одного эмулятора другому?

Tags: android, c#, .net, monodroid, xamarin-studio

Требуется запустить два эмулятор  для отладки приложения в xamamarin studio. Просто что бы один эмулятор отправил СМС-сообщение другому. Выбрал я [WindowsAndroid](http://windowsandroid.ru.uptodown.com/). В [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/151080/) на Хабре было описано чтобы это сделать нужно вместо номера телефона ввести порт эмулятора. Но ничего не выходит.

```
   button.Click += delegate
    {
        SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage("2497", null,
                          "Hello from Xamarin.Android", null, null);

    };
```

[image: Порт]

При отправке Смс- ничего не происходит, пробовал написать сообщение в ручную но результат тот же.

[image: Неудача=(]

Все разрешения добавлены в манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App2.App2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:label="App2" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
  </uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
  </uses-permission>
</manifest>
```